# How does reading a file from a char[] array work in File handling?

Tags: java, file-handling

This is a code of copying text of one file to another.

```
   public class Writer 
   {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
      File f=new File("D:/test.txt");
      FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
      char cbuff[]=new char[(int)f.length()];
      int c=fr.read(cbuff);

     fr.close();

      FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("D:/newTest.txt");
     fw.write(cbuff);
        fw.close();
    }   
    }
```

I wanna know what this line does

> char cbuff[]=new char[(int)f.length()];

**How does FileReader recognizes to store the text of file it's reading into this cbuff[]?**

**When I comment this line**

> int c=fr.read(cbuff);

**the code doesn't work.Why?**

Comment: This code is wrong to start with; a file's length is in bytes, this is not a 1-to-1 mapping with chars.

Comment: @fge This code  is right and working,I have used it,u copy it and run

Comment: No it's not; try and copy a file encoded in UTF-16... And it will badly fail for binary files

Comment: @fge hold on man I am just reading a simple text file,I don't wanna read "a file encoded in UTF-16",as per task I just wanna read a simple text file everytime,I just wanna know How does FileReader recognizes to store the text of file it's reading into this cbuff[]?

Comment: Even a "simple text file" is not as simple as you make it sound; for instance, this code uses the default JVM encoding: how do you know that the text file you read uses _this_ particular encoding? If you try and read a UTF-8 encoded file where the JVM has a windows-1252 encoding by default, you'll corrupt the destination file

Comment: @fge because I am creating the files manually before reading it.

Comment: And you think that is a reason? I can use notepad++ and create a text file with _any_ encoding. If you use notepad, this will be windows-1252.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f.length(); // gives us the length in bytes, the type of the result is 'long'
(int) f.length(); // casts the long to an int
char cbuff[] = new char [(int) f.length()]; // create a new variable, which is an array of char and is called cbuff. assign a new array of char to it, with the length specified by the length of the file
```

Here's the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28char%5b%5d%29) showing that FileReader.read(char[]) reads from the file into an array. It's actually a method inherited from the Reader class.

```
fr.read(cbuff); //this is the line that does the actual reading from the file f. The results are stored in the char array cbuff (which is why we initialized it to be the length of the file)
```

Now, the result of fr.read() is stored in an int, that's just the number of characters that have been read. Unless there is an error, this should be the exact same as the length of cbuff.

Answer (score 2):

OK, first of all, here is a code which will work for *any* file, not just text files:

```
final Path src = Paths.get("D:/test.txt");
final Path dst = Paths.get("D:/newTest.txt");
Files.copy(src, dst);
```

Now, the code you have is severely broken. Let us start with this:

```
char cbuff[]=new char[(int)f.length()];
```

This will create an array of `char`s the same size as the file size; but it does not account for the fact that `byte`<->`char` mapping is not 1 to 1. For instance, if the file is encoded in UTF-8, "à" is encoded in *two* bytes; the char array will therefore be at least too long by one element. It is even worse in UTF-16 (each `char` is two `byte`s) or even UTF-32.

Second problem:

```
FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
```

No encoding is specified; the default JVM encoding is used.

As such, if you try and read a file encoded in UTF-8 with a default JVM encoding of windows-1252, you will *corrupt the destination file*.

The same goes for the output file: no encoding specified. Such a file is essentially "non portable".

Third problem: there is:

```
int c=fr.read(cbuff);
```

This will return the number of characters actually read; good.

But this isn't used when you write the file back! The write code should be:

```
fw.write(cbuff, 0, c);
```

Comment: FileReader fr=new FileReader(f); instead of this line how can I specified manually the encoding which works for all files.

Comment: No encoding will work for all text files... You have to know the encoding used by advance. But the most commonly used encoding is UTF-8. For instance `new FileReader(f, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char cbuff[]=new char[(int)f.length()];
```

Create the char array with the size equal to the length of the file (content of file)

```
int c=fr.read(cbuff);
```

Read the file and put the content in the char array

Comment: That is what I am asking how can read method write code in a char array and I have read oracle docs regarding working of read method and I am unable to find any source which says this "Read the file and put the content in the char array".Can you give me source of your answer?

Comment: @TruePS The actual implementation of this metthod is done in StreamDecoder class of package sun.nio.cs

Answer (score 1):

> I wanna know what this line does
>
> > char cbuff[]=new char[(int)f.length()];

This line simply creates a new char array that has the same length as the input file.

> int c=fr.read(cbuff);

This line then reads the input file and stores it in the char array (cbuff).
If you comment this last line, the content of the input file is never written to the cbuff, so when you try to write it to the new file, it is empty.

Comment: That is what I am asking how can read method write code in a char array and I have read oracle docs regarding working of read method and I am unable to find any source which says this "Read the file and put the content in the char array".Can you give me source of your answer?

Comment: Check this source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read(java.nio.CharBuffer)

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
char cbuff[]=new char[(int)f.length()];
```

basicly initializes the container in the memory, where the file will be loaded, it does not read the file though. The line

> int c=fr.read(cbuff);

reads the file into the memory buffer. How come you were expecting it to work without that line? And regarding your question - "How does FileReader recognizes to store the text of file it's reading into this cbuff[]?" - is basically because of that line...

fr.read(cbuff); // translation: File reader, please read the file into the buffer cbuff.

Hope this helps